# Convert timestamp (in milliseconds) to boost ptime

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I need to convert the a time measured in milliseconds since the epoch to a `boost::posix_time::ptime`. The only function I see is to convert is `from_time_t` but that is only in seconds and would lose the milliseconds.

How can I convert from milliseconds since epoch to a ptime type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from_time_t(millis / 1000) + millisec(millis % 1000)
```

Comment: Yes, that should work (sometimes the simple answer can be elusive ;)

Answer (score 13):

Where `ms` is your milliseconds count since the epoch:

```
ptime epoch_milliseconds_to_ptime(unsigned long int ms)
{
  static const ptime epoch(date(1970, 1, 1));

  return epoch + milliseconds(ms);
}
```